# Why this batch file does not work?

Tags: batch-file

```
@echo off

set /p host=

for /f "delims==< tokens=4" %%b in ('ping %host% -n 1 ^| findstr "Reply"') do (set ttl=%%b)

if '%ttl%' GTR "64" (echo operating system: Windows - ttl=%ttl%) else (echo operating system:   linux - ttl=%ttl%)

pause
```

**Why this batch file not work correctly?**

Comment: What is it supposed to be doing, and what is it _actually_ doing?

Comment: Because there is an error.  Please ask a specific question to get a specific answer (read the SO help and check out the section about how to write good questions); your question is off-topic here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
set /p host=
set "ttl="
for /f "delims==< tokens=4" %%b in ('
    ping "%host%" -4 -n 1 ^| findstr /I "TTL"
') do (set /A "ttl=%%b")
if defined ttl (
  if %ttl% GTR 64 (
     echo operating system: Windows - ttl=%ttl%
  ) else (
     echo operating system:   linux - ttl=%ttl%
  )
) else echo unknown "%host%" host
```

Changes:

- `set "ttl="` to empty/delete the `ttl` variable, see next `if defined ttl`;
- `ping "%host%" -4 -n 1`:

  - `"%host%"` as currently written, `%host%` could evaluate to an empty string and `ping ""` results to `ping "%COMPUTERNAME%"`;
  - `-4` to force `IPv4` as `ping ""` defaults to `IPv6`;
- `findstr /I "TTL"` as for possible `Reply from a.b.c.d: Destination host unreachable`;
- `set /A "ttl=%%b"` for next comparison;
- `if %ttl% GTR 64` ( try results: `'' GTR "64"` *false*, `'1' GTR "64"` *true* etc.);
- `if defined ttl`.